# node_modules folder too large

Tags: javascript, gulp, node-modules, package.json

I've been using Gulp for quite a while and either I didn't notice it took this much space from the beginning or the sizes have been growing.

I only use it for very normal front-end work. For example, this is the request part of my `gulpfile.js`:

```js
var gulp         = require('gulp'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    browserSync  = require('browser-sync'),
    concat       = require('gulp-concat'),
    copy         = require('gulp-copy'),
    del          = require('del'),
    htmlmin      = require('gulp-htmlmin'),
    merge        = require('merge-stream'),
    streamqueue  = require('streamqueue'),
    cleancss     = require('gulp-clean-css'),
    gulpif       = require('gulp-if'),
    newer        = require('gulp-newer'),
    imgmin       = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    plumber      = require('gulp-plumber'),
    postcss      = require('gulp-postcss'),
    order        = require('gulp-order'),
    rename       = require('gulp-rename'),
    runSequence  = require('run-sequence'),
    sass         = require('gulp-sass'),
    sourcemaps   = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    uglify       = require('gulp-uglify'),
    uncss        = require('gulp-uncss');
```

---

Now, according to `du -sh`, node_modules weighs 2.2GB which I think is way too much. I wanted to dig a bit deeper so I looked all root modules:

[image: DaisyDisk look at a regular node_modules/ folder]

---

I'm probably being naive here but I'm just expecting some javascript functionality, I don't see how or why these modules, especially the top ones, can be so large in size.

Is this just how Gulp is designed? Am I doing it backwards? Can I improve this (besides not using it/those)?

Comment: Whats in your `package.json`?  Gulp wouldn't effect your `node_modules`.

Comment: Check this out. Here is a website that shows how many other dependencies your dependencies have.  uncss is really large because it has so many other dependencies. http://npm.anvaka.com/#/view/2d/uncss

Comment: Insane! Nice site too. I was wondering, since there are plenty of cross dependencies, that's just waste space right? For example, if module A and B need lodash, I'm installing it twice? Coming back to my case, nothing to do then, this is what it is?

Comment: Excuse me for a very primitive suggestion, but did you try deleting `node_modules` and `npm i` again? Sometimes there's some cruft left when you just `npm i` without `--save`, they never enter the `package.json` and sometimes you never use those packages.

Comment: @Lucas absolutely. Actually in each project I have to `npm i`. Take `uncss` for example, it's taking **242MB**. Think about how many lines of javascript there are in 242MB of space. Something's not right.

Comment: Everyone should be looking into their node_modules at least a little bit in their spare time. There are some weird things in there that shouldn't be. Unused dist/ directories with minified/unminified files, multiple copies (x64 and x86) of .exe files which couldn't run on your system anyway, packages that use huge libraries only to borrow their stripIndents functions... It's the culmination of "I'll just use a couple dependencies..." repeated hundreds of times. Exponential growth.

Comment: So are we all in agreement here? Is this a tedious manual process of experimental excision (meaning that it will never get done) or are there tools to make this easier?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some ways that comes to my mind:

1. It's more about your package.json, so if you could optimize it, it's a very good option:

   - separate packages as devDependencies and dependencies, it helps to decrease the node_modules size in production mode (when you use the `–production` flag on npm install).
   - replace some libs that are big in size or having so many dependencies with lighter libs or libs with fewer dependencies.
2. Use [node-prune](https://github.com/tj/node-prune) or [modclean](https://github.com/ModClean/modclean) or other packages like these, to remove unnecessary files from node_modules.